# C++ variadic templates find out type

Tags: c++, templates

I have these templates:

```
template<size_t DestinationVariableId, size_t SourceVariableId>
struct store {
    static constexpr size_t destinationVariableId = DestinationVariableId;
    static constexpr size_t sourceVariableId = SourceVariableId;
    static constexpr int instruction = 2;
};

template<size_t DestinationVariableId, size_t SourceVariableId>
struct add {
    static constexpr size_t destinationVariableId = DestinationVariableId;
    static constexpr size_t sourceVariableId = SourceVariableId;
    static constexpr int instruction = 3;
};

/-------------enable_if_else-------------
template<bool Cond, typename TrueType, typename FalseType>
struct enable_if_else;

template<typename TrueType, typename FalseType>
struct enable_if_else<true, TrueType, FalseType> {
    using type = TrueType;
};

template<typename TrueType, typename FalseType>
struct enable_if_else<false, TrueType, FalseType> {
    using type = FalseType;
};

//-------------static_list-------------
template<class ...Elements>
struct static_list {};

//-------------static_list_get-------------
template<size_t Idx, class List>
struct static_list_get;

template<size_t Idx, class FirstElement, class ...Elements>
struct static_list_get<Idx, static_list<FirstElement, Elements ...>>
    : static_list_get<Idx - 1, static_list<Elements ...>> {
};

template<class FirstElement, class ...Elements>
struct static_list_get<1, static_list<FirstElement, Elements ...>> {
    using type = FirstElement;
};

//-------------execute_s-------------
template<int index, class ...Commands>
struct execute_s;

template<int index, class ...Commands>
struct execute_s <index, static_list<Commands ...>> {
    static constexpr int value = enable_if_else < static_list_get<index, static_list<Commands ...>>::instruction == 1, add<0, 0>::instruction , store<1, 1>::instruction >;
};
```

In execute_s I want to check if the command at given index is of type add or store and return given output.

How can I check at compile time in the template struct execute_s of what type is the command at given index?
`enable_if_else < static_list_get<index, static_list<Commands ...>>::instruction == 1, add<0, 0>::instruction , store<1, 1>::instruction >;` is not working as the ::instruction is not clear from the general command.

Comment: Please add the compiler error message to the question.

Comment: Also please show an example of how you're using the `execute_s` class. See how to make a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

`::instruction` is an `int`, so you can't pass it as an argument to `enable_if_else`, at least as a type. You could pass it as a non-type template parameter, but in fact, you don't need `enable_if_else` at all. You could just initialize `value` like this:

```
static constexpr int value = [] { 
    return static_list_get<index, static_list<Commands ...>>::instruction == 1 ? 
           add<0, 0>::instruction :
           store<1, 1>::instruction;
}();
```

Comment: it gives an error that instruction is not a member of ....